# Column validation on a non required field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, validation, column-validation

I would like to have validation on a column that IF you type in the field you have to use 19 letters. But if you leave the field blank you can still save.

Right now I use this:

```
=IF(LEN([column 1])=19
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([column 1]), true, IF(LEN([column 1])=19, true, false)
```

This will allow users to add either blank values or the text with length of **exact**  19 characters.