# SharePoint text field user should able to enter 6-digit alphanumeric characters only

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, list-form, validation

SharePoint text field user should be able to enter 6-digit alphanumeric characters only.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint column validation formula like below for allowing only 6-digit alphanumeric characters:

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("!",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("~",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("#",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("$",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("%",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("*",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("(",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(")",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("+",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(";",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("[",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("]",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",[Title])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("\",[Title])),TRUE),LEN([Title])=6)
```

You can adjust (add/remove) the special characters in above validation formula as per your requirements.

**Column settings**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

**Reference**: [Column validation on a non required field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275153/column-validation-on-a-non-required-field/275154#275154)

---

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.